# Is it possible to use mongo field value as pattern in $regex [mongo db]?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

lets say i have data

```
 db = [ 
   { "make": "audi", "year": "2018", "url": "xyz.com/makes-2019-"},
   { "make": "audi", "year": "2013", "url": "abc.com/car/audi-2013"}
]
```

lets say i need to query data if make or year is present in url.
for eg. something like this

```
db.cars.aggregate([
   {
     "$match": {
       "$or": [
         { "url": {"$regex": $model, "$options": "i"}}, 
         { "url": {"$regex": $year, "$options": "i"}}
       ]
     } 
    }])
```

this seems to  not work any workaround except map-reduce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`$indexOfCP`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfCP/) to check whether the `url` string contains the `make` sub string

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "$expr": {
      "$ne": [
        { "$indexOfCP": ["$url", "$make"] },
        -1
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7uLiw0W9FSg)