# regex with variable pattern taken from value of a field [MongoDB]

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aws-documentdb

Let's say I have some documents of this shape:

```
[
  {
    name: "Name1",
    surname: "Surname1",
    fullName: "Name1 Surnmame1"
  },
  {
    name: "Name2",
    surname: "Surname2",
    fullName: "Name2 Surnmame2"
  },
  // I would like to detect this one where name and name inside fullName do not match
  {
    name: "Name3",
    surname: "Surname3",
    fullName: "Name1 Surnmame3"
  }
]
```

and `fullName` is a computed field.

Ideally, I would like to detect the documents for which `name` is not part of `fullName`. This could happen due to some wrong implementation of the computation part.

I would expect something like the following would at least identify which name/fullname do really match (the opposite of what I am trying to do):

```
db.people.find({"fullName": /"$name"/});
```

However, this searches for `$name` and not for the value that field `name` holds in the same document. Any idea how to accomplish this?

**Note:** I try to run this against DocumentDB (v3.6.0) but if you have any suggestion for MongoDB it could work as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use mongo field value as pattern in $regex \[mongo db\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54891457/is-it-possible-to-use-mongo-field-value-as-pattern-in-regex-mongo-db)

Comment: @nimrodserok not exactly. As I have commented on the accepted answer by @ray, ```$expr``` is not supported in my case of DocumentDB (v3.6.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$indexOfCP` to check if the `name` is in `fullName`. If the substring is not present, `$indexOfCP` will return -1.

According to the [official AWS documentDB document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html), `$indexOfCP` should be supported in your v3.6 DB.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      idx: {
        "$indexOfCP": [
          "$fullName",
          "$name"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      idx: -1
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kG2b4MPuasK)for your reference.

Comment: This is what I need but I was unlucky here (Feature not supported: 303): `$expr` is not supported in DocumentDB...

Comment: @LuckyLuke Can you see if [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kG2b4MPuasK) works for you?

Comment: @LuckyLuke Thanks for confirming. I have updated the answer correspondingly